# How to convert ListNode from LeetCode to regular list?

Tags: python

Trying to solve LeetCode "Add Two Numbers".

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

I wrote a program that deals with lists while LeetCode provides ListNode. Unfortunately i'm not able to understand ListNode mechanics (how to iterate through, how to get length and so on). So i decided to convert it into list. Please help me how to do it, how to iterate through all ListNode and put all of it values to the regular list and then vice versa: list -> ListNode in order to return my answer in correct type.

Here is piece of my code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        l3 = [] #resulting list
        shift = 0 
        
        # HERE goes code for: ListNode -> List

        if len(l1) > len(l2):
            l_long = l1
            l_short = l2
        else:
            l_long = l2
            l_short = l1
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is probably not what leetcode expects you to do. I suggest you take a while to try to figure out how ListNode works, instead of trying to convert it into a list.

Answer (score 4):

The question doesn't require you to use regular lists. Since the lists are stored in "reverse order", that actually helps because you would add digits individually between both lists, then calculate/carry overflows moving left-to-right. For example, adding linkedlists `[5, 1] + [5]` would cause you to add one node to the resulting list `[0,` , then you iterate to the next position, carrying forward the 10s digit, then do 1 from your input plus 1 from the carry of the previous iteration, getting `2` , so the result is `[0, 2]`. If you carry a 1 into a 9, then you bring the carry digit forward again

Besides, if you're going to build a regular list, you might as well convert to an int, instead, do the math, then turn the int into the linked list...

But to convert a LinkedList into a regular list, without that LinkedList class being an iterable type itself, would look like this

```
ll = ListNode(...)

l = []
n = ll
while n is not None:
    l.append(n.val)
    n = n.next
```

Otherwise, if it were a proper Python iterable type, `[n.val for n in ll]`

Comment: And if it were a *proper* proper iterable: `list(ll)` :-). Would be unusual to hand out its structural components instead of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation at the beginning of the code, as it gives you an explanation regarding linked lists. If that is not enough, I suggest you check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_linked_lists.htm) out. Converting the linked list into a regular list would make the assignment moot. See
[this](https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/introduction-to-linked-list#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20Linked%20Lists,to%20create%20trees%20and%20graphs.) for even more resources about linked lists.

In a nutshell, a linked list answers the need for an unlimited data structure (of course, no data structure is actually unlimited, but linked lists certainly allow more flexibility than arrays, for example). A linked list is made of nodes, each pointing at the next node, with the last node pointing at null. That way, if you want to lengthen your list, you simply make a new node and make the last node to point to it. In addition, each node holds a value. In the implementation given in your question, `self.val` is the value holder for each node, and `self.next` is the pointer to the next node.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch iterability into those linked lists with this:

```
def ll_iter(node):
    while node:
        yield node.val
        node = node.next
ListNode.__iter__ = ll_iter
```

Then in your code you can just do:

```
l1 = list(l1)
```

But I think it's simplest to just write a recursive solution working with the linked lists directly. You don't even get recursion depth problems, as the lists are guaranteed to have at most 100 nodes.